# Can you reference a class from another solution in Dynamics 365 Cloud?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I'm currently developing Dynamics 365 solutions in Power Apps. They have similar functional requirements, so I've created a base SDK solution with several common code and helper classes. I'm hoping now to create several optional add-on solutions that depend on the SDK solution.

I've created a plug-in assembly in the SDK solution, but I'm struggling to understand how can I reference these classes from a separate solution.

Do I add the SDK plug-in assembly to the dependent solutions within Power Apps by going to *Add Existing -> More -> Developer -> Plugin Assembly*? Will it know to take a dependency on the SDK solution?

Or do I import the assembly locally within Visual Studio (but then how does it resolve in Dynamics)?

I've read the [build and package plug-in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/build-and-package) to get this far, but am struggling with the last mile. Hoping someone can steer me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended path is to register your plugins as NuGet packages. You can add referenced library assemblies to those packages. The Dataverse systems identifies assemblies in your package having classes implementing the `IPlugin` interface automatically.

The option for registering plugins as NuGet packages is relatively new and is supported by Visual Studio extension [**Power Platform Tools for VS 2022**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/devtools-vs) and by the [**Power Platform CLI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/cli/introduction?tabs=windows).